# Is there a contextual difference between раздражать (кого-то) and досаждать (кому-то)?

Tags: грамматика

Is there a contextual difference between раздражать (кого-то) and досаждать (кому-то)?

Answer (score 4):

yes

`досаждать` is a deliberate action, that is `to harass`, `to molest` and it doesn't necessarily indicate the actual emotional response of the object

`раздражать` is `to annoy`, `to irritate` involuntary by one's natural demeanor or qualities, where the object is clearly emotionally disturbed